# Why Does Automattic use SVN for WordPress Instead of Git?

Tags: svn, git

I use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) on my development and I find it to be reliable so I wonder what is the reason Automattic choose to use [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) for WordPress?

Comment: You'll probably get more (and better) answers if you clean up and clarify your question, and your question title.

Comment: Your question isn't really a question, and it seems a bit argumentative at that.  -1 for lack of clarity and the fact that your non-question can't really be answered.

Comment: @tnorthcutt : sorry for the tone and stuff. but it's really a curious question. no politic ;D

Comment: This question is hard to answer by me (and probably anybody else), because I did not made that decision. So you must ask the person who decided to use subversion for the WordPress project to find out more in specific. I don't know the name of the person who made the decision, so sorry for not being very helpful.

Comment: it's ok. i came here based on your latest post. thank you for that ;D

Comment: I use ClearCase for all my development and it find it reliable so I wonder what is the reason Automattic choose to use svn for WordPress?

Comment: For reference: in December 2010, there was [a very interesting discussion about switching to Git](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-December/036379.html) on the wp-hackers mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More then likely it is personal preference. Some people like the workflow introduced by SVN, and some just don't like the distributed model of Git. Some like the way commits, branches, tags etc are handled in one revision control over another.

It could also be that they where using SVN before Git was stable enough and they don't want to go through and switch.

Why fix something that isn't broken?

I really don't think there is a good answer you are going to get on this board, unless someone from Automattic is here. There isn't a right or wrong answer in picking version control systems.

Answer (score 9):

WordPress moved to Subversion [in 2003](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1/trunk).  Git (as a project) was started [in 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#Early_history).

Absent Doc Brown's flux capacitor coming to fruition, I think the reasons for SVN over Git are rather obvious.

(Hint: they rhyme with "fistory", "finertia" and "forganizational fomentum")

Comment: That's an objective reason, indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does a lot of things backwards. (Maybe they like to be different?) A couple things that come to mind are...

1. They refuse to exhibit clean code standards, and in fact reject anyone's attempts to clean up their code. (Proof: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/code-refactoring/)
2. SVN is tragically slow, and so places like https://SVNHub.com even tell you to use GitHub instead. (Strangely GitHub supports SVN... what's that all about?)

It's pretty depressing when WordPress does everything wrong in those critical points above, but yet they still power 41% of the internet at the time of writing. (Source: https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/cm-wordpress)

So, why does WordPress use SVN instead of Git? To be different! It's broken, but they refuse to fix it.